# How do I cluster a block of code into levels (Python)

Tags: python

! I am trying to build a small game in Python to guess random numbers within a range. The code will randomly choose a number between 1,20 and ask the user to guess the number 3 times.

I need help in clustering the block of code below into a Level (Say Level 0). If the player is able to guess correctly the player advances to the next Level (Level 1)

I need further help here where i change the conditions of Level 1's range to 1,30.

```
import random

secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
print(" I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.")

#Ask the player to guess 3 times.
for guessTaken in range(1,4):
    print("Take a guess. ")
    guess1 = int(input())
    if guess < secretNumber:
        print("Your guess is too low")
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print("Your guess is too high")
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print("Good job! you guessed my number in " + str(guessTaken) + " guesses! Move onto the next level")
else:
    print("Nope. The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber))

secretNumber1 = random.randint(1,30)
print(" Welcome to level 1 I am thinking of a number between 1 and 30.")
for guessTaken1 in range(1,4)
    guess = int(input())
    print("Take a guess. ")
    guess1 = int(input())
    if guess1 < secretNumber1:
    print("Your guess is too low")
    elif guess1 > secretNumber:
        print("Your guess is too high")
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber1
    print("Good job! you guessed my number in " + str(guessTaken) + " guesses! Move onto the next level")
else:
    print("Nope. The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber1))
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at implementing this new feature?

Comment: if the player misses 3 times the games ends ?

Comment: You obviously need to recreate your `secretNumber` and restart the loop for asking input, so which of those are you having issues with?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am having trouble restarting the loop in pycharm

Comment: @DanIonescu yea the game ends if they guess incorrectly three times with the comment "Nope. The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I tried looping it but its giving me errors in Pycharm (Apologies this is my first week of learning programming)

Comment: please show your attempts with an  [edit] and the errors you get so we can explain what you did wrong

Comment: @cricket_007 what i tried was to just create another set of variable and repeating the same commands after the first cluster (see code above)

Comment: In your edit, you've failed to mention any errors, but `print("Your guess is too low")` is not indented properly

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry the error reads 
    if guess1 == secretNumber1
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Your missing a colon there as well as in `for guessTaken1 in range(1,4)`

Comment: @cricket_007 ah ok I see it. Sorry for the noob errors first week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import random

def guess_number(max_number):
    print(" I am thinking of a number between 1 and {0}.".format(max_number))
    secret_number = random.randint(1, max_number)

    for guess_taken in range(1,4):
        print("Take a guess. ")
        guess = int(input())
        if guess < secret_number:
            print("Your guess is too low")
        elif guess > secret_number:
            print("You guess is too high")
        else:
            return (True, guess_taken)

    return (False, secret_number)

level = 1
for max_number in range(10, 30, 5):
    print("Current level: {0}".format(level))
    guessed = guess_number(max_number)
    if guessed[0]:
        print("Good job! you guessed my number in " + str(guessed[1]) + " guesses!")
    else:
        print("Nope. The number I was thinking of was " + str(guessed[1]))
        print ("Game over!")
        break
    level += 1
```

Sample output:

```
Current level: 1
I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10.
Take a guess. 
6
You guess is too high
Take a guess. 
3
Your guess is too low
Take a guess. 
5
Good job! you guessed my number in 3 guesses!
Current level: 2
I am thinking of a number between 1 and 15.
Take a guess. 
7
Your guess is too low
Take a guess. 
10
Your guess is too low
Take a guess. 
13
You guess is too high
Take a guess. 
12
You guess is too high
Nope. The number I was thinking of was 11
Game over!
```

Comment: thank you this works wonders! Just a comment on for max_number in range(10, 30, 5) does this mean it will grow by 5 at each level until it reaches 30 as the maximum range?